# What do we call the analogous version of free abelian group when $A$ is an arbitrary abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

For homology with coefficients, we often have that the chain group $C_n(K)$ is comprised of elements of the form $\sum g_i\sigma_i$ where $g_i\in A$ for some abelian group $A$ and $\sigma_i$ is some $n$-simplex.

What do we call the structure for $C_n(K)$?

When $A=\mathbb{Z}$, we say that $C_n(K)$ is a **free abelian group**.

How about for other arbitrary $A$? Is there any name like "free something"?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a free $A$-module.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Thanks. But I thought $R$ has to be a ring to be $R$-module?

Comment: true, but for most common choices of coefficients it is a ring: $\mathbb Z_p, \mathbb Q,\mathbb R$ etc.